# Java->Bouncycastle-> Show example operations

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am new to cryptography and would like to get started.
I know `(somehow I was able to write these 2 options for creating key pairs)`

Using `bouncycastle` classes I need :

```
- 1)Create a Curve25519 key pair.
```

How to use this pair for:

```
- 2)Encryption/Decryption

- 3)Data Signing/Signature Verification
```

## key pair generation

```
ProviderUtils.getProvider():
```

```java
new BouncyCastleProvider();
```

- first option:

```java
final BouncyCastleProvider provider = ProviderUtils.getProvider();
final KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(XDHParameterSpec.X25519, provider);
keyPairGenerator.initialize(new XDHParameterSpec(XDHParameterSpec.X25519));
final KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
System.out.println(keyPair);
System.out.println(keyPair.getPrivate());
```

output:

```bash
java.security.KeyPair@1324409e
X25519 Private Key [86:45:fc:74:0f:8c:d1:c2:ed:3c:0c:ae:b9:3f:3f:84:19:05:d2:b3]
    public data: 2c823d1015ffa4a8ce427618a7a383b6c3de9cfc63cf97b4f48ae2407aa5a267
```

- Second option:

```java
final X25519KeyPairGenerator x25519KeyPairGenerator = new X25519KeyPairGenerator();
final X25519KeyGenerationParameters params = new X25519KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom());
x25519KeyPairGenerator.init(params);
final AsymmetricCipherKeyPair kp = x25519KeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
System.err.println(kp);
System.err.println(kp.getPrivate());
```

output:

```bash
org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair@68837a77
org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.X25519PrivateKeyParameters@6be46e8f
```